# Expression for intersection of lines in terms of points defining the lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm writing a program that renders images, and I'm trying to figure out (as part of a bigger problem) an expression for the point $(\alpha,\beta)$ as pictured below, as a function of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$.

[image]

Hopefully one that would work for basically any configuration of the 4 initial points (except of course if it makes the lines parallel).

It kinda seems like it should be really easy but I don't know how to begin. Writing parametric expressions for the lines makes a mess.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it important that the intersection occurs on the line segment *between* the points, or can it occur anywhere along the lines joining the pairs of points?

Comment: @TheoBendit It can occur anywhere.

Comment: Also, do you care about nearly parallel lines?  The naive implementation of the mathematically correct answer is numerically unstable.

Comment: I always come back to this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282) Stack Overflow answer when coding segment-segment intersection

Comment: @SamFreedman That answer is mathematically correct (if you have infinite precision arithmetics instead of floating point numbers) but numerically unstable, as are most answers on that page.

Comment: @user10354138 If the lines are nearly parallel, I can handle the case separately with a different method. I guess I would need to know how near to parallel makes the naive implementation unstable. BTW, is that answer linked by Sam what you would call the naive implementation?